# Get last occurrence (if 1+ occurred) OR first scheduled (if none occurred)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I've got a table in SQL Server that represents doctor/patient encounters. One of the columns is a datetime field that represents when the encounter began. There is another field that represents the SCHEDULED time for the encounter.

I'm trying to write a query to isolate one encounter (for a given day) that meets the following criteria:

1. If any encounters have begun, the LAST encounter to begin, – OR –
2. If NO encounters have begun, the FIRST scheduled encounter

So, I kind of want the following:

```
SELECT 
    TOP 1 * 
FROM 
    TABLE 
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN STARTED IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC, 
    IF STARTED IS NULL
        SCHEDULED ASC
    ELSE
        STARTED DESC
```

I realize that I can't do that exactly, but I was wondering if I'm missing some other way to do this.

Other information:

1. All encounters to be compared will occur on the same calendar day.
2. This is part of a larger query where I'm partitioning by the room in which the encounter occurred/is scheduled.
3. As long as I can accurately identify that one encounter, I don't care about the rest of the encounters in that room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it was particularly clear in my question, but based on the specific criteria of my scenario, the answer was a lot easier than I thought.

Basically, it boils down to the fact that I want to split the rows into 2 groups:

1. Rows with a non-null value in the STARTED column, and
2. Rows with a null value in the STARTED column.

Also important is the fact that there is ALWAYS a valid value in the SCHEDULED field.

I want to sort group #1 by their STARTED values in descending order and group #2 by their SCHEDULED values in ascending order.

Then, I want the first entry from group #1, or - if group #1 is empty - the first entry from group #2. No other entries are important for this problem.

Because group #1 is desired to be sorted in descending order, the following solution is what I've used:

```
SELECT 
    TOP 1 * 
FROM 
    TABLE 
ORDER BY 
    STARTED DESC,
    SCHEDULED ASC
```

In my testing, this gives me the row with the latest STARTED value, or the row with the earliest SCHEDULED value, if all rows have a null STARTED value.

Answer (score 2):

Try sorting like this:

```
SELECT 
    TOP 1 * 
FROM 
    TABLE 
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN STARTED IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
    STARTED DESC, 
    SCHEDULED ASC
```

Comment: If you check the answer that I posted, you'll see a lot of similarity to your suggestion, but it turns out that the CASE statement isn't necessary (because I'm sorted STARTED DESC). Of course, the CASE statement WOULD be necessary if I was wanting non-null STARTED values at the top of the list, but still sorted ASC.

Answer (score 0):

Nicked the sorting method from Johann

```
Select Top 1
  *
From (
  Select
    0 As X,
    *
  From
    Encounter
  Where
    -- started after 00:00:00 today (maybe Started > GetDate() will suffice)
    Started >= DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, GetDate()), 0) And 
    -- started before 00:00:00 tomorrow
    Started < DateAdd(day, 1 + DateDiff(day, 0, GetDate()), 0)
  Union All
  Select
    1 As X,
    *
  From
    Encounter
  Where
    -- Sechduled after 00:00:00 today
    Scheduled >= DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, GetDate()), 0) And 
    -- started before 00:00:00 tomorrow
    Scheduled < DateAdd(day, 1 + DateDiff(day, 0, GetDate()), 0) 
  ) a
Order By
  X,
  Started Desc,
  Scheduled Asc
```

With the assumption that started is always on the same day as scheduled, and scheduled is not nullable, this is equivalent to:

```
Select Top 1
  *
From
  Encounter
Where
  -- Sechduled after 00:00:00 today
  Scheduled >= DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, GetDate()), 0) And 
  -- started before 00:00:00 tomorrow
  Scheduled < DateAdd(day, 1 + DateDiff(day, 0, GetDate()), 0) 
Order By
  Case When Started Is Null Then 0 Else 1 End,
  Started Desc,
  Scheduled;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9cc65/3